# Eclipse PDE logging missing method

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

So I am reading this [FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_use_the_platform_logging_facility%3F):

It mentions `getLog()` method which is not available. My current class is basically extending `AbstractHandler`. How am I supposed to use this?

Comment: From the link you've given us: Quote: "*The log for a plug-in is accessed from the plug-in’s class, using getLog inherited from Plugin.*" You'll need to access the log from you Plugin's class your `AbstractHandler` class is residing in.

Answer (score 2):

If you let Eclipse create the Activator class for you and you specified the 'This plug-in will make contributions to the UI' option then the class will look something like:

```
public class Activator extends AbstractUIPlugin {

    // The shared instance
    private static Activator plugin;

    public Activator() {
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        super.start(context);
        plugin = this;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop(final BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        plugin = null;
        super.stop(context);
    }

    public static Activator getDefault() {
        return plugin;
    }
}
```

You can then call

```
ILog log = Activator.getDefault().getLog();
```

to access the log interface

Answer (score 0):

From the FAQ: "*The log for a plug-in is accessed from the plug-in’s class, using getLog inherited from Plugin*". This means, you need to access the log from your own plugin's class.

So, essentially, you'll need to add in your `AbstractHandler` following:

```
ILog log = MyPluginClass.getInstance().getLog();
```

Remember, that `getInstance()` is not a standard method, but plugins are supposed to work as singletons. So, you maybe need to add this method.

The method is documented in the [Eclipse Help](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2Fplugin%2FAbstractUIPlugin.html) which is a good reference documentation if you have any questions regarding Eclipse and its implementation.

Comment: What is `MyPluginClass` here? is it the current class? If so, then there is no getInstance() method, and it doesn't make sense to implement that when it would be pretty much the same as using `this`?

Comment: Since you're using `AbstractHandler` I assume you are creating an Eclipse plugin. So, there is an `(AbstractUI)Plugin` class in your project. Make your mind. How could your `AbstractHandler` be a `Plugin` anyway?

Comment: I have only two classes in my entire plugin. One is an Activator class that extends AbstractUIPlugin, the other one is a Button Handler class that extends AbstractHandler. In both Activator and Button Handler class instances there are no such thing as `getLog`.

Comment: There should be an `getLog()` method in your `BundleActivator` (which is a subclass of Plugin). See [Eclipse Help](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2Fplugin%2FAbstractUIPlugin.html)